# MySQL - create a datetime using current_date and a specific time

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time

I have a time column [start_at] in a chores table. I want to populate table daily_chores with the current_date + time column from the chores table.

Example: I have chore number 17 which should start at 18:00:00. On date 2016-06-24, the daily_chores table should be populated with a statement like this (but it doesn't work):

```
INSERT INTO DAILY_CHORES (actual_day, chore_number, chore_starts )
SELECT CURRENT_DATE, c.chorekey, add_time(CURRENT_DATE,c.start_at)
FROM CHORES c;
```

This row shoud be created (amongst others):

```
actual_day  chore_number  chore_starts
----------  ------------  -------------------
2016-06-24      17        2016-06-24 18:00:00
```

Is it possible to add a fixed time to a variable date in a sql statement that adds up to a datetime?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
add_time(CURRENT_DATE,c.start_at)
```

use

```
str_to_date(concat(CURRENT_DATE, " ", c.start_at), "%Y-%m-%d %T")
```

Example:

```
str_to_date(concat("2016-06-24", " ", "18:00:00"), "%Y-%m-%d %T")
```

returns the `DATETIME` object "June, 24 2016 18:00:00".